# How do I get Ubuntu working on a Nexus 7 (2013)?

Tags: nexus-7

Can anyone tell me whether the information at "https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation" still holds for the 2nd generation Nexus 7?  I'm thinking that there may be new compatibility issues, since the hardware/chipset changed.  If the images don't work for Nexus 7 (2013), are there any plans to migrate to and support this device?

Thanks for any help and advice.

Comment: Other than screen size (7"), the **Nexus 7 2** has more in common with **Nexus 4** (phone) than old model.

Comment: @ThomasW. OP linked to the instalation of the desktop version of ubuntu, this question is not about touch

Answer (score 10):

Best answer (for now):

from: https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg03337.html

> We'll still just support the old Nexus 7 for now, as we first need to
>   start the port for the latest device. It should work, but the main
>   problem is that the device is based on Android 4.3 by default, so it
>   requires us to make our layer compatible with that as well (at least
>   the 4.3 based binaries).
>
> Don't have the device, so can't give more details, but don't see why
>   not (we would at least have the same possibility to distribute
>   binaries, so we could also produce such a build once the port is
>   done).

---

### **Update, 27-Feb-2014:**

I have ***Ubuntu Touch 14.04 beta*** (build 209) running on my **ASUS Nexus 7 (2013)**, 16GB, WiFi device. (I also updated my **LG Nexus 4**, 16GB smartphone, to build 209, using same method.)

I used the new **ubuntu-device-flash** tool. The code itself is based on the (fairly new) AOSP ('Android Open Source Project') 4.4.2 source code, and is a **major** improvement over earlier efforts.

*Be patient.*

The instructions on 'Install' page are partially updated, but do show how to do the install.

[Flashing a phone/tablet with Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install)

Once I have this repeatable, I will post details (if 'Install' page not updated) ..