# Need instructions for installing ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, nexus-7

[This guide from wiki](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#Manual_Installation) seems old and confusing.

For my situation:

- device: Nexus 7 (grouper)
- origin OS: Android 4.3
- recovery: TWRP (3rd party recovery)

And I tried as following steps:

1. Download `saucy-preinstalled-touch-armel+grouper.zip` and `saucy-preinstalled-touch-armhf.zip` from [CDimage.Ubuntu webpage](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/current/)
2. `adb push` two zip files into `/sdcard`
3. `adb reboot recovery`
4. select `/sdcard/saucy-preinstalled-touch-armel+grouper.zip` to do an update
5. repeat step 3, select `/sdcard/saucy-preinstalled-touch-armhf.zip` to do another update
6. reboot, still Android

---

additional info

```
shell@grouper:/ $ ls /data/ubuntu
SWAP.swap
bin
boot
dev
etc
home
lib
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var
```

**How can I install Ubuntu touch (instead of Android) on my device?**

Answer (score 1):

### There are a couple of obvious issues:

(1.) The 'Manual Installation' instructions appear to be incomplete (for a full install).

The two files are used to 'update' an existing install. A 'full install' has 3-4 more steps.

Try using the provided tool, as described on the Wiki.

**`phablet-flash -b`** (full install, current) or

**`phablet-flash -b --pending`** (full install, untested daily)

*From there, you can probably create the extra manual steps.*

To download all files first (without a device attached) use:

**`phablet-flash -d grouper -b -D`** (current)

**`phablet-flash -d grouper -b -D --pending`** (untested daily)

---

(2.) The *Google (ASUS) **Nexus 7*** ('grouper') is the 2012 model.

If you have (manually) upgraded your **Nexus 7** to Android **4.3**, or have a brand new **Nexus 7 2** (2013 model) with Android **4.3**, this may cause major issues.

*Either wait a few weeks, or start again with a **Nexus 7** (2012) still running Android 4.2.2 (or earlier).*

Comment: as you mentioned android 4.3 may cause issues, does it means that install ubuntu touch will not wipe whole android? anyway I'll give it a try first.

Comment: I would downgrade to 4.2 first. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/326670/ubuntu-on-2nd-generation-nexus-7

Comment: Install from Android 4.3 Succeeded. so far so good

Comment: The 'current' Ubuntu Touch uses an LXC container 'Android' layer to interface certain hardware functions. This is based on Android 4.2 binaries (assumed to be present). *I suggest loading a full Android 4.2.2 factory build (from recovery instructions)*