# Ubuntu core on new Nexus 7?

Tags: nexus-7, ubuntu-core

Does Ubuntu Core (not Ubuntu Touch) also work on [the new Nexus 7 with 1080p screen](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7)?

It doesn't yet mention anything about the newer Nexus 7, just wondering if it is supported?

If it is not supported, does Ubuntu have any plans to support it going forward?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/326670/ubuntu-on-2nd-generation-nexus-7

Answer (score 1):

I have Ubuntu ARM running on my nexus 7.  All this revision 2 stuff with a hardware change seems a little ominous, but it works fine for me with the exception of having trouble with the tiny buttons for shutdown/restart.

Comment: So just to confirm, you have the new rev.2 1080p nexus? Oh and is there no way to scale the desktop then? I totally understand it would be tiny at 1080p on 7". By the way the reason I'm asking is that I'm thinking of getting a 7 for this purpose (running Ubuntu desktop) and if the new one works well it would be a nice upgrade with its extra memory.

Comment: i have a rev 1 nexus

Comment: Ah ok thanks, I was looking for experiences with the rev2 as I'm thinking which one to buy.